# Using water filter/purification system on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, water, borer-separating

(Being asked as a theoretical question. Obviously everyone should ask their LOR.)

There is a water filter (or purifier) that works in the following way:
The water flows into a part where there is some sort of "chemical" (in the shape of round white balls) that help to "clean the water". The water then pours from there out going through a normal sort of filtering part. If we look at the water is the "ochel" (food) and the white balls as the "pasules" (not good part) is there a problem of borer in the fact that the water (the "ochel" in this case) passes through this filter, "separating" it from the white balls (the "pasoles" in this case.) Perhaps this is "borer b'cli" (separating with a vessel) and would be prohibited on Shabbos.

I'm pointing this out because it's not a "normal case" of using a filter where the water simply passes through a sort of sifting part (which could be muter on Shabbos if a person would drink this water without having used the filter.) The water is getting mixed together with some sort of chemical then "separated" from that so in regards to the chemical we have a "mixture" of "ochel and pasoles".)

Comment: Can you link to or show this filter? I've never heard of a filter like this. To filter water, the water has to flow through the filter, not just near it.

Comment: @Ariel of course it flows through the filter! The "purifying process" happens when it passes through and mixes with this "chomer" or whatever it is. Then the water exists through a point on the cli where there is a normal "filter". The information I gathered from someone who installs many types of filters in peoples homes.

Comment: So what is this "chomer"? I've never heard of a filter with such a thing. Can you link to any examples?

Comment: BTW I'm not asking to be annoying - understanding the construction of the filter can help understand what exactly is happening to the water.

Comment: @Ariel Many filters work like this actually. In some way or another. How else is the water "cleaned"? I will try and find an example online. The point is the water gets to a stage where one may not be able to drink it when it's running through the part with this "chomer".

Comment: No, no filter works like this. The water never has any "chomer" mixed into it. You may be thinking of Flocculation, but water filters don't work that way. In a water filter the water passes through the active material (usually, but not always, carbon) which kind of "glues" the impurities to the material (this is called Adsorption, with a d not a b). There's never a stage when anything is added. The more the water touches the active material, the more impurities get removed. Filters are made to slow down the water to give it time to touch a lot of the surface area and remove all the impurities.

Comment: @Ariel Would someone be able to drink the water when it's mixed with the carbon?

Comment: Yes actually, carbon tastes good in water, sort of sweet. But in a filter the carbon is in the form of a solid block and stays in the filter, it doesn't really mix with the water, but rather the water passes through it.

Comment: White balls of the sort your mention are generally for the removal of chlorine and some other chemicals.  They are not a screen that water passes through, though in both cases something that was previously in the water is left behind.  A third kind of filter uses carbon in a similar way to the white balls, but leaving more.  Some filters involve a UV light, which I think is more complex even when always-on: in this case the light destroys microorganism by cutting them into smaller bits.  The cut bits may remain ('benignly') in the water that you drink.

Comment: [Here is a link](http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/question209.htm) that describes the same: 'filters' that work by surface contact with water, not as a screen.  When they say 'surface contact' you can understand that, at a very fine level, the surface is very rough and water flows into all these craggy fissures and contaminants get stuck in the 'sharp corners', then the cleaned water flows back out.

Comment: After listening to the shiur that Boruch posted, I perhaps understand your question. You are asking if granule based filters are a problem of borer. But even in a granule filter they never really mix. If you spill the "mixture" out on the floor, all the water will drain away, leaving the granules behind - it doesn't actually mix, just like a wet shirt isn't a mixture.

Comment: @Ariel maybe you want to post what this psak is?

Answer (score 2):

Rav Nissan Kaplan just discussed this aspect in his weekly Halacha Shiur in the Mir. Download the shiur at [Using Water Filter on Shabbos](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/aud/5773-Halacha/5773-019-water_filters_on_shabbos.mp3)

Comment: summarizing the content of the shiur would be helpful otherwise this would be better served as a comment

Comment: What's the outcome from the shiur?

Answer (score 2):

Mori WeRabi, Harav Mansour Shelit"a holds that it is Mutar to use a water filter on Shabbat providing that the water is drinkable without the filter.

[source](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=2171&txtSearch=water%20filter)