# Is one allowed to use a nasal filter or gas mask on Shabbat or Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology

These are products that are used to protect from chemicals/pollen/dust allergy or pet hair.

A water filter I see would be mussar if the water is basically clean as was already asked here:
[Using water filter/purification system on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28124/using-water-filter-purification-system-on-shabbos)

What if the air wasn't that dirty just possibly damaging or irritating; would the same hold true?

Comment: You can even use a REGULAR water filter on shabbos if it's used in potable water. It's a chumra of the rashba (I think) that says that the standard for consumable is individual rather than collective. In doing so, he justifies using a stricter guideline than maachal Ben drosai (edible to a minority). If people in general have no problems breathing without the mask or filter, then using it on shabbos would be fine. There is no melacha centered around air quality like there is for food or water.

Comment: The question would probably involve carrying in reshus harabim or treating it as an article of clothing. It would also involve whether or not someone would take it off outside. A gas mask would probably involve pikuach nefesh as opposed to a regular surgical mask or nasal filter.